# Match with optional surrounding brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regular expression to match strings like `a = (foo)a`:

```
([a-z]+) = \(foo\)\1
```

Now the second `a` may also be in brackets and I need to match that as well which led to:

```
([a-z]+) = \(foo\)(?:\1|\(\1\))
```

Is there any way to make this expression simpler? I don't want to match unbalanced brackets (e.g. `a = (foo)(a`) so `([a-z]+) = \(foo\)\(?\1\)?` would not work. If it were the same character(s) (e.g. `"`) the regex could look like `([a-z]+) = \(foo\)("|)\1\2`.

As an example those should match:

```
a = (foo)a
a = (foo)(a)
```

On the other hand those should not match:

```
a = (foo)(a
a = (foo)b
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3rNgSe/2)

Comment: Is it not enough simple? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use parentheses pattern only once in the regex, you can use a [**conditional construct**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) (note it is not "simple"):

```
([a-z]+) = \(foo\)(\()?\1(?(2)\))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QuYVNc/1).

*Details*:

- `([a-z]+)` - Group 1 (`\1`):
- `= \(foo\)` - space, `=`, space, `(foo)` string
- `(\()?` - Group 2: an optional group capturing a `(` char
- `\1` - Same value as in Group 1
- `(?(2)\))`  - a conditional construct that matches `)` only if Group 2 participated in the match.